# Pythonic switching using functions inside a class

Tags: python, class, switch-statement

I am attempting to use a dict to control function selection from within a class, however, I get this following TypeError:

```
TypeError: A() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Example code:

```
class Tt:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def A(self):
        print("a")
    def B(self):
        print("b")
    def C(self):
        print("c")

    a_diction={
         '0' : A,
         '1' : B,
         '2' : C
    }

    def ad(self,data):
        self.a_diction[data]()
```

How should I construct this switch in `ad` to provide `self` to both `a_diction` and to the called method `A`, `B`  and `C`?

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that you're missing an argument. I suggest adding an argument.

```
self.a_diction[data](self)
```

Comment: yes, this works.... but why did it work?
logically it should have been 
self.(self.a_diction[data])() .. which is wrong i know..
but passing self as an argument here works.. why so?

Comment: @user3007395 can you post your actual code in the question? The code that is there as it stands will not work, even with this addition.

Comment: It works because `someObject.method()` can also be called using the syntax `someClass.method(someObject)`. Similarly, `self.thing()` and `thing(self)` both work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do the following instead?

```
class Tt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_diction = {
             0: self.A,
             1: self.B,
             2: self.C
        }

    def A(self):
        print("a")

    def B(self):
        print("b")

    def C(self):
        print("c")

    def ad(self,data):
        self.a_diction[data]()
```

I.e., make `a_diction` an instance attribute and initialize it in `__init__`?  Then you can choose bound methods as values in the dictionary instead of unbound methods.